# Slug error in django

Tags: python, django, slugify

I am new to django and currently learning the basics. However, I am stuck with the slug module.

Hope to find a solution. Thanks in advance.

While running the migration command

```
python manage.py makemigrations rango
python manage.py migrate
```

I keep getting this error:

```
django.db.utils.IntegrityError: UNIQUE constraint failed: rango_category__new.slug
```

Models.py file

```
from django.db import models
from django.template.defaultfilters import slugify

class Category(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=128, unique=True)
    views = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    likes = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    slug = models.SlugField(unique=True)

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.slug = slugify(self.name)
        super(Category, self).save(*args, **kwargs)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.name


class Page(models.Model):
    category = models.ForeignKey(Category)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=128)
    url = models.URLField()
    views = models.IntegerField(default=0)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.title
```

The tutorial says 
"Since we did not provide a default value for the slug, and we already have existing data in the model, then the migrate command will give you two options. Select the option to provide a default, and enter ‘’. Dont worry this will get updated shortly. Now re-run your "populate.py" script. Since the save method is called for each Category, the overrided save method will be executed, updating the slug field. Run the server, and inspect the data in the models via the admin interface." (link of the tutorial is mentioned in point 3 at the bottom)

populate.py file

```
import os
os.environ.setdefault('DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE', 'kiran_blog_project.settings')

import django
django.setup()

from exodus.models import Category, Page


def populate():
    python_cat = add_cat('Python',128,64)

    add_page(cat=python_cat,
        title="Official Python Tutorial",
        url="http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/",views=20)

    add_page(cat=python_cat,
        title="How to Think like a Computer Scientist",
        url="http://www.greenteapress.com/thinkpython/", views=19)

    add_page(cat=python_cat,
        title="Learn Python in 10 Minutes",
        url="http://www.korokithakis.net/tutorials/python/",views=17)

    django_cat = add_cat("Django",64,32)

    add_page(cat=django_cat,
    title="Official Django Tutorial",
    url="https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.5/intro/tutorial01/",views=30)

    add_page(cat=django_cat,
        title="Django Rocks",
        url="http://www.djangorocks.com/",views=21)

    add_page(cat=django_cat,
        title="How to Tango with Django",
        url="http://www.tangowithdjango.com/",views=50)

    frame_cat = add_cat("Other Frameworks",32,16)

    add_page(cat=frame_cat,
        title="Bottle",
        url="http://bottlepy.org/docs/dev/",views=13)

    add_page(cat=frame_cat,
        title="Flask",
        url="http://flask.pocoo.org",views=16)

    # Print out what we have added to the user.
    for c in Category.objects.all():
        for p in Page.objects.filter(category=c):
            print "- {0} - {1}".format(str(c), str(p))

def add_page(cat, title, url, views):
    p = Page.objects.get_or_create(category=cat, title=title)[0]
    p.url=url
    p.views=views
    p.save()
    return p

def add_cat(name,views,likes):
    c = Category.objects.get_or_create(name=name)[0]
    c.views=views
    c.likes=likes
    c.save()
    return c

# Start execution here!
if __name__ == '__main__':
    print "Starting  population script..."
    populate()
```

So my question is,

1.After selecting the option to provide the default value
what value should I enter?

2.Also the instruction states that, I need to run "populate.py" file. But before running this file, I think I need to include the slug field. So can someone specify the changes in the "populate.py" field?

3.[my django tutorial link](http://www.tangowithdjango.com/book17/chapters/models_templates.html#update-category-table-with-slug-field)

4.[Solution to this same query, I even tried out the answer using uuid but did not work out.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29373887/django-db-utils-integrityerror-unique-constraint-failed-rango-category-new-sl#)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to alter your migration file to avoid unique constrains. According this [instruction](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/howto/writing-migrations/#migrations-that-add-unique-fields), modify your last migration file(which added the slug field to the model) like this:

Model: `slug = models.SlugField(unique=True, default=uuid.uuid1)`

Migration file: (i.e: `0004_category_slug.py`)

```
class Migration(migrations.Migration):

    dependencies = [
        ('yourproject', '0003_remove_category_slug'),
    ]

    def gen_slug(apps, schema_editor):
        for row in Category.objects.all():
            row.slug = slugify(row.name)
            row.save()

    operations = [
        migrations.AddField(
            model_name='category',
            name='slug',
            field=models.SlugField(default=uuid.uuid4),
            preserve_default=True,
        ),
        migrations.RunPython(gen_slug),

        migrations.AlterField(
            model_name='category',
            name='slug',
            field=models.SlugField(default=uuid.uuid4, unique=True),
        ),
    ]
```

Comment: @rudra I deleted all my migration files & wrote my model without the slug field & applied all the migrations & was successful. In the next step I introduced the slug field in my models and ran the migration commands then i got this error. `django.db.utils.IntegrityError: UNIQUE constraint failed: exodus_category__new.slug
` I don't understand how the name of category became category_new. I am not getting what is wrong here.

Comment: @user61092 If you delete all the migrations files and db then there is no need to apply the migration's code as written in the answer. But if you don't delete them(db+migrations file), then you need to re-write the migration file just like this answer's example. BTW, I don't see why category should be renamed. If you face the same problem again, then please put your migration file's code in your question.

Comment: @rudra I have only deleted my migrations file and not the db. I don't know how to delete the db. Can you guide me through the process?

Comment: @user61092 DB means database. Just drop your database (if sqlite then delete it).

Comment: @rudra I deleted my db and followed the entire process and updated the migration file as you stated and finally got my app running and slugify() working as well. Thanks a ton!

Comment: Welcome :) Then please accept this answer, so that it may help others.