# UNIQUE constraint failed

Tags: django

I am going through Tango with Django and I can't solve this excercise.
I get `django.db.utils.IntegrityError: UNIQUE constraint failed: rango_category.name` error. This is after I try to implement `views` attribute to `Category` object. This is a excerpt from my database population script. I though maybe that I should `makemigrations` and then `migrate` to update models for DB. However, this didn't help.

```
    cats = {
    'Python' : {'pages': python_pages, 'views':128},
    'Django': {'pages': django_pages, 'views':128},
    "Other Frameworks": {'pages':other_pages, 'views':128},
    }

for cat, cat_data in cats.items():
    c = add_cat(cat, cat_data['views'])
    for p in cat_data["pages"]:
        add_page(c, p['title'], p['url'])

for c in Category.objects.all():
    for p in Page.objects.filter(category=c):
        print("- {0} - {1}".format(str(c), str(p)))

def add_cat(name, views):
    c = Category.objects.get_or_create(name=name, views=views)[0]
    c.views=views
    c.save()
    return c
```

Adding `Category` model:

```
class Category(models.Model):
name = models.CharField(max_length=128, unique=True)
views = models.IntegerField(default=0)



class Meta:
    verbose_name_plural = 'Categories'

def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

Comment: Check this!
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29373887/django-db-utils-integrityerror-unique-constraint-failed-rango-category-new-sl

Comment: I think this is because `name` field in `Category` has the argument `unique=True` Show your models `Category`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You got the error because `unique = True` in `name = models.CharField(max_length=128, unique=True)` means that Django will raise constraint errror *UNIQUE constraint failed* in case you trying to save a new instance with the same `name` value; A violation of the unique constraint

`get_or_create` doesn't work because `views=views` that may be different even though `name` equals `name`

When you `create` or `get` your instance, you can do so with only the `name` field

```
def add_cat(name, views):
    c = Category.objects.get_or_create(name=name, views=views)[0]
    c.views=views
    c.save()
    return c
```

Answer (score 3):

As mentioned in comments, the error is caused by violation of the unique constraint on `Category.name`.  The reason that this is happening might not be completely obvious, however.  When you call `Category.objects.get_or_create`, you are asking django to look for an object with both the given name *and* the given number of views.  If one is not found, then django tries to create one, which violates the unique constraint if there is already a `Category` of the same name, but with a different number of views.  Depending on desired behavior, you can fix by either:

- remove unique constraint altogether
- change unique constraint to a [`unique_together` constraint](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/models/options/#unique-together)
- change the model reference to first get or create by name, then set (or modify) the views attribute (don't forget to save)