# UNIQUE constraint failed: auth_user.username integrityError

Tags: python, django, authentication

im getting this error when i want that the username not be repeated in my django form.
i saw a lot of this situations here in stackoverflow but it seems that every situation is unique.

every time that i want to create a new user the error pops out and i dont know why i review my code but i have no idea where could be the error.

i hope that someone could help me with this error. 
regrets

> forms.py

```
from django import forms
from django.contrib.auth.models import User


class RegisterForm(forms.Form):
    username = forms.CharField(required=True, min_length=4, max_length=50, widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={ 'class': 'form-control', 'id': 'username'}))
    email = forms.EmailField(required=True, widget=forms.EmailInput(attrs={ 'class': 'form-control', 'id': 'email', 'placeholder': 'example@hotmail.com'}))
    password =  forms.CharField(required=True, widget= forms.PasswordInput(attrs={ 'class': 'form-control'}))

    def clean_username(self):
        username = self.cleaned_data.get('username')

    if User.objects.filter(username=username).exists():
        raise forms.ValidationError('El username ya esta en uso')
        return username

    def clean_email(self):
        username = self.cleaned_data.get('email')

    if User.objects.filter(email=email).exists():
        raise forms.ValidationError('El email ya esta en uso')
        return username
```

> views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.shortcuts import redirect

from django.contrib import messages
from django.contrib.auth import login
from django.contrib.auth import logout
from django.contrib.auth import authenticate

from django.contrib.auth.models import User

from .forms import RegisterForm

def index(request):
    return render(request, 'index.html', {
        'message': 'Listado De Productos',
        'title': 'Productos',
        'products': [
        {'title': 'Playera', 'price': 5, 'stock': True}, #producto
        {'title': 'Camisa', 'price': 7, 'stock': True},
        {'title': 'Mochila', 'price': 20, 'stock': False},
        ]
       })

def login_view(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        username = request.POST.get('username') #diccionario
        password = request.POST.get('password')
        user = authenticate(username=username, password=password)
        if user:
            login(request, user)
            messages.success(request, 'Bienvenido {}'.format(user.username))
            return redirect('index')
        else:
            messages.error(request, 'Usuario o Contrasena no validos')
    return render(request, 'users/login.html', {})

def logout_view(request):
    logout(request)
    messages.success(request, 'Sesion Cerrada Exitosamente')
    return redirect('login')

    def register(request):
    form = RegisterForm(request.POST or None)
    if request.method == 'POST' and form.is_valid():
        username = form.cleaned_data.get('username')
        email = form.cleaned_data.get('email')
        password = form.cleaned_data.get('password')

        user = User.objects.create_user(username, email, password)
        if user:
            login(request, user)
            messages.success(request, 'Usuario Creado Exitosamente')
            return redirect('index')
    return render(request, 'users/register.html', {'form': form})
```

Comment: Thanks for coming to SO! Posting the errors and traceback will help people diagnose the problem and provide possible solutions.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [UNIQUE constraint failed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50747412/unique-constraint-failed)