# integrity error for a variable that does not exist

Tags: django, python-3.x

> (django.db.utils.IntegrityError: UNIQUE constraint failed: items_purchase.item_id)

This is the error that I get when I try to migrate the app named 'items'.

```
app name = items
model name = Purchase
```

I don't understand what is `item_id`.

```
class Purchase(models.Model): 
    name=models.CharField(max_length=200) 
    phone=models.IntegerField(default=0) 
    email=models.EmailField() 
    address=models.CharField(max_length=200) 
    pin=models.IntegerField(default='0') 
    state=models.CharField(max_length=200)


class Item(models.Model): 
    name=models.CharField(max_length=200) 
    c=models.ForeignKey(Category, on_delete=models.CASCADE) 
    photo=models.ImageField(default='0') 

    def __str__(self): 
        return 'Item: {}'.format(self.name)


def confirm(request): 
    f=PurchaseForm(request.POST) 
    if f.is_valid(): 
        name = f.cleaned_data['name'] 
        phone = f.cleaned_data['phone'] 
        email = f.cleaned_data['email'] 
        address = f.cleaned_data['address'] 
        pin = f.cleaned_data['pin'] 
        state = f.cleaned_data['state'] 
        f.save() 
        template=loader.get_template('items/confirm.html') 
        context={'f':f} 
        return HttpResponse(template.render(context,request))
```

Comment: Can you please share your model?

Comment: class Purchase(models.Model):
    name=models.CharField(max_length=200)
    phone=models.IntegerField(default=0)
    email=models.EmailField()
    address=models.CharField(max_length=200)
    pin=models.IntegerField(default='0')
    state=models.CharField(max_length=200)

Comment: class Purchase(models.Model):
    name=models.CharField(max_length=200)
    phone=models.IntegerField(default=0)
    email=models.EmailField()
    address=models.CharField(max_length=200)
    pin=models.IntegerField(default='0')
    state=models.CharField(max_length=200)

Comment: Did this model contains data or you are newly creating it?

Comment: doesnt have any preloaded data. the user has to enter the data through the website created.

Comment: NOT NULL constraint failed: items_purchase.user_id

Comment: def confirm(request):
    f=PurchaseForm(request.POST)
    if f.is_valid():
        name = f.cleaned_data['name']
        phone = f.cleaned_data['phone']
        email = f.cleaned_data['email']
        address = f.cleaned_data['address']
        pin = f.cleaned_data['pin']
        state = f.cleaned_data['state']
        f.save()
        template=loader.get_template('items/confirm.html')
        context={'f':f}
        return HttpResponse(template.render(context,request))



this is the view function after you enter the data

Comment: then python manage.py makemigrations work correctly?

Comment: makemigrations work properly.

Comment: i get the error when i execute, "manage.py migrate"

Comment: make sure db is empty

Comment: but there are other models with data. that would be erased if i clear the database. right?

Comment: Is thre table clalled items

Comment: if that model exists then post that model structure

Comment: yes. there is a table called 'Item'

Comment: class Item(models.Model):
    name=models.CharField(max_length=200)
    c=models.ForeignKey(Category, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    photo=models.ImageField(default='0')
    def __str__(self):
        return 'Item: {}'.format(self.name)

Comment: but why would Purchase have a column called item? there is no foreign key

Comment: and what's this?" items_purchase.item_id "

Comment: thats strange! https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29373887/django-db-utils-integrityerror-unique-constraint-failed-rango-category-new-sl/29374126 try this. It may help

Comment: thanks but I still dont understand what i did wrong.

Comment: I added some of the code you posted here in comment to your question. Please check if this is correct so and please use the `edit` button and add *ALL* necessary information to your question! Don't use comments for this!