# "UNIQUE constraint failed" when migrate

Tags: django

Error message：

```
Operations to perform:
  Apply all migrations: admin, auth, contenttypes, contest1, dashboard, sessions, tiaozhancup
Running migrations:
  Applying dashboard.0012_auto_20200104_1633...Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\acer\Desktop\来了喔\venv\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\utils.py", line 84, in _execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "C:\Users\acer\Desktop\来了喔\venv\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\sqlite3\base.py", line 383, in execute
    return Database.Cursor.execute(self, query, params)
sqlite3.IntegrityError: UNIQUE constraint failed: new__dashboard_teacher.TID
```

models.py

```
class Student(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, primary_key=True)
    username = models.CharField(max_length=50, blank=True, null=True) #这个是为了能在admin能用，就当他是真实姓名吧，管它呢
    email = models.EmailField(max_length=254, blank=True, null=True)
    phone_number = models.CharField(max_length=50, blank=True, null=True)
    SID = models.CharField(max_length=50, blank=True, null=True, unique=True,) 
    gender = models.CharField(max_length=50, blank=True, null=True)
    school = models.CharField(max_length=50, blank=True, null=True)
    contest = models.CharField(max_length=500, blank=True, null=True, default='[]')

class Teacher(models.Model):
    really_a_teacher = models.BooleanField('真的是老师吗 ?', default=False)
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, primary_key=True)
    username = models.CharField(max_length=50, blank=True, null=True)
    email = models.EmailField(max_length=254, blank=True, null=True)
    phone_number = models.CharField(max_length=50, blank=True, null=True)
    TID = models.CharField(max_length=50, blank=True, null=True, unique=True,)
    gender = models.CharField(max_length=50, blank=True, null=True)
    department = models.CharField(max_length=50, blank=True, null=True)
    authorization_for_contest = models.CharField(max_length=500, blank=True, null=True, default='[]')
```

I add 'unique=True' to SID and TID respectly, somehow only TID part get error when I migrate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create a data migration and run the before the model migration and in that migration fetch all teachers with the same TID and assign them unique TID or if the objects all duplicate then delete their one of the instances.

You can open shell of django using `python manage.py shell` & execute the below code.

```
from django.db.models import Count
Teacher.objects.values('TID').annotate(tid_count=Count('TID'))
```

this would output in this form

```
[
   {'TID': '56', 'tid_count': 2}, 
   {'TID': '98', 'tid_count': 4}
]
```

This will help you to debug and find out which TID is causing error in your migration.

For more detail, you can go through [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29373887/django-db-utils-integrityerror-unique-constraint-failed-rango-category-new-sl) question