# How to add unique_together constraint to a Django table with prior data

Tags: django, django-models, unique-constraint

I am trying to implement a `unique_together` constraint on one of the models in my Django project. The decision to have a unique constraint was taken after **test data was already created in the table**.

Now while running migrations, I came across the following error:

> django.db.utils.IntegrityError: UNIQUE constraint failed:
>   movt_frt.frt_group_id,
>   movt_frt.rec_loc_id,
>   movt_frt.dis_loc_id

I have tried creating similar unique constraints on table that previously held no data and **migrations happened successfully**.

### My question is:

1. **Am I right in concluding** that *the Migration is failing because the table already has data residing in it*?
2. Is there a way to do some changes to the **migration file** on the lines as [discussed here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29374126/12379095) and attempt migration again, to run successfully?

I am using **Django ver. 2.0.6**

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if this question is still relevant. It's not so much that the table is filled with data. These data already contains combinations that conflict with your specified 'unique_together'.
Overruling is not possible, but if the table is not too big you could correct it manually.

Comment: Even if it's not relevant for the OP, having an answer is relevant to the SO community